# Can't cast File as Blob

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to cast a File as a Blob but apparently I can't even File being a subclass of Blob.

I've tried it like this: `<Blob>file` and this: `file as Blob`.
And the error is always the same:

`Type 'File' cannot be converted to type 'Blob'. Property 'size' is missing in type 'File'.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following displays no errors at all.

```
declare const file: File;

const blob = file as Blob;
```

Make sure your TypeScript version is up to date (2.3.2 is the latest as of this writing)

[You can see this in action in the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20const%20file%3A%20File%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20blob%20%3D%20file%20as%20Blob%3B)

Comment: I removed my node_modules and updated to 2.3.2 now and the error persists (the code you used to test throws the same error), could it be a problem with my framework? I'm using Ionic 3 (Angular 4).

Comment: are the types `File` and `Blob` the ones declared in lib.d.ts (go to definition)?

Comment: I added a playground link to the example. You can see that it works.

Comment: Thanks @Aluan! It turns out that Ionic overrides the typescript definitions and they managed to mess the File definition, I'll fix it locally for now and then file a bug report. Your suggestion to go to definition really saved me!

Comment: Glad to help. Ionic does weird things. Definitely file a bug!